# Why does my variable not increment after one time?

Tags: python, button, canvas, tkinter

When the user submits their answer and its wrong, def getResult() should make the "mistake" variable goes up by 1 when the user makes their first error and mistake changes from 0 to 1. After that, when the user enter a wrong answer, the variable still ends up as "1" again. Is there any way for it to always increment when the user is wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()

root.wm_title("HangMan")

canvas = Canvas(root, height=400, width=800)
canvas.pack()
name = ''

def titlescreen():
    title = canvas.create_text(400, 100, font=("Times New Roman", 50), tags="title")
    canvas.itemconfig(title, text="HANGMAN: THE GAME")

    startButton = Button(canvas, text="Start Game", width=10, command=startgame)
    canvas.create_window(400, 200, window = startButton)

    creditsButton = Button(canvas, text="Credits", width=10, command=displaycredits)
    canvas.create_window(400, 250, window = creditsButton)

def startgame():
    def getName(nameEntry):
        global name
        name = nameEntry.get()
        print (name)
        drawPole()



    canvas.delete(ALL)
    welcome = canvas.create_text(400,100,font=("Times New Roman",50),text="WELCOME!")
    welcome2 = canvas.create_text(400,150,font=("Times New Roman", 30),text="PLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME")


    nameEntry = Entry(canvas)
    enterName = Button(canvas, text="Enter", width=10, command=lambda: getName(nameEntry))


    canvas.create_window(350, 200, window = nameEntry)
    canvas.create_window(490, 200, window = enterName)


    nameEntry.delete(0,END)
    nameEntry.insert(0, "Enter Player Name")


def displaycredits():
    canvas.delete(ALL)
    created = canvas.create_text(400,100,font=("Times New Roman",50),text="CREATED BY")
    credit1 = canvas.create_text(400,150,text="Patrick Tsui & Ricardo Perez")
    credit2 = canvas.create_text(400,170,text="Montclair State University Students")
    backButton = Button(canvas,text="Back to Title Screen",width=30,command=backtotitle)
    canvas.create_window(400, 200, window=backButton)

def backtotitle():
    canvas.delete(ALL)
    titlescreen()

def drawPole():
    canvas.delete(ALL)
    a = canvas.create_rectangle(550,50,550,350,fill = "black")
    b = canvas.create_rectangle(350,50,550,50,fill = "black")
    c = canvas.create_rectangle(350,50,350,90,fill = "black")
    gamePlay()   


def gamePlay():

    def getAnswer():
        global answer
        answer = answer1.get()
        print (answer)

        getResult()

    def getResult():
        global result2
        global mistake
        mistake = 0
        result2 = result

        if str(result2) == answer:
            canvas.create_text(300, 375, text="Correct!",fill="green", tags="result")
        else:
            canvas.create_text(300, 375, text="Wrong!",fill="red", tags="result")
            d = canvas.create_oval(325, 90, 375, 140, outline = "black")
            mistake += 1

        print (result2)
        print (mistake)
        Continue()

    def Continue():
        canvas.delete("confirm")        
        continueButton = Button(canvas,text="Continue",width=10,command=gamePlay)
        canvas.create_window(450, 350, window = continueButton, tags="continue")


    canvas.delete("question")
    canvas.delete("continue")
    canvas.delete("result")
    x = random.randint(1,100)
    y = random.randint(1,100)
    questions = random.randint(0,3)

    answer1 = Entry(canvas)
    confirmButton = Button(canvas,text="Confirm",width=10,command=getAnswer)

    canvas.create_window(300, 350, window = answer1)
    canvas.create_window(450, 350, window = confirmButton, tags="confirm")

    answer1.delete(0,END)
    answer1.insert(0, "Enter Your Answer")

    if questions == 0:
        result = x + y
        question1= canvas.create_text(350, 300, text=("Add: " + str(x) + " + " + str(y)), tags="question")


    if questions == 1:
        result = x - y
        question1= canvas.create_text(350, 300, text=("Subtract: " + str(x) + " - " + str(y)), tags="question")


    if questions == 2:
        result = x * y
        question1= canvas.create_text(350, 300, text=("Multiply: " + str(x) + " * " + str(y)), tags="question")


    if questions == 3:
        result = x // y
        question1= canvas.create_text(350, 300, text=("Divide: " + str(x) + " / " + str(y)), tags="question")

titlescreen()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand; you reset `mistake` to 0 immediatly before incrementing in your `getResult` function. How do you expect it to ever get greater than 1?

Comment: @helmbert, there is no `mistake` variable, or is there?

Comment: @ForceBru, yes, there is an assignment in the `getResult` function (which is an inner function of `gamePlay`). Hm, line numberings in the code blocks would be helpful for discussions like this... :)

Comment: @helmbert, I've also noticed it, but the global variable called like this was not declared. Well, this code is too long to search through.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining too well :(  I was frustrated and I'm still learning python right now. I feel like a newb for not noticing that. But thanks guys for helping me to find the error. I fixed it now by assigning it after the imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to declare the `mistake` variable right after the imports:

```
mistake=0
```

If you don't do this, all the `mistake` variables in your functions will be local.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I corrected my error and it works now.